What is the difference between a one sample t test of the difference between two groups versus a two sample t test comparing the two groups?
Let us say that we currently have two independent groups $G_1, G_2$ with equal sample numbers $n_{G_1} = n_{G_2}$ and may not have equal variances $ {\sigma_1}^2 \neq {\sigma_2}^2$. If the statistical question to be asked are if the two groups are different, I can see two ways of asking this question:

Compare the two groups $G_1, G_2$ against each other using a two sample t test and testing the null hypothesis: $H_0 : \mu_1 = \mu_2$

Take the difference of the two groups (let's say $\Delta_x = \mu_1 - \mu_2$)and testing the null hypothesis: $H_0 : \Delta_x = 0$


My intial feeling is that the two are essentially asking the same question. The reason for this is as follows:

Let us say $x_1, x_2$ are from groups $G_1, G_2$ respectively. The
difference between them is defined as $\Delta_x = x_1 - x_2$.
Thus $\forall x_1 \in G_1, \forall x_2 \in G_2, \exists \delta_x \in
\Delta_x ( \delta_x = x_1 - x_2 ) $.
When running the two sample t test, we are comparing $\mu_1 = \mu_2$ where $\mu_1 = \overline{x_1}$ and $\mu_2 = \overline{x_2}$
We can essentially rearrange the equation such that it we are now asking $\mu_1 - \mu_2 = 0$.
When examining whether or not $\Delta_x = 0$, we are essentially
asking if $\Delta_x = 0 = \overline{x_1 - x_2} =
\overline{\delta_x}$ .
Arithmetically these are the same, and when comparing the outputs of
both operations (i.e.   $\overline{x_1 - x_2}$ vs $\overline{x_1} -
\overline{x_2}$). Turns out $\overline{x_1 - x_2} = \overline{x_1} -
\overline{x_2}$

However, even with the above outcome, the outputs from the statistical tests were different. The null hypothesis for $H_0:\Delta_x = 0$ was rejected, but the null hypothesis for $H_0:\mu_1 = \mu_2$ was not. Why is that? And since this occurred, it would suggest that the two tests are asking similar, but different questions. What is this difference?

The pairs in the paired t-test exist on the observation level, not just on average; it is applicable when for every observation in group 1 you have a matching one in group 2 to subtract from it. It allows for dependence between these two observations (the trade-off being that it considers only the difference between the two).

@PBulls How does this manifest with regards to the math? I'm not sure I understand how it allows for dependence between the two observations, and why it is the dependency that matters. I envision drawing samples from a population set for both $x_1, x_2$ and the same could be applied for $x_1 - x_2$. I don't see where the dependency plays a role here. Could you provide more context for this?

I'm not entirely sure that I understand, but it seems possible that your first #1 and #2 are indeed answering the same question. The estimate of the relevant variance for the $\Delta$ in #2 leads you to having the same calculation for Student's t as the setup in #1. The t-test is of course a test for sample means.

@MichaelLew I am inclined to agree but the outputs of the tests differ and I'm not sure why they are different. I can only think it has something to do with how the t test assumes how the samples were drawn from the real population distribution, but I can't envision it since I don't know how it could be different.

If the outputs differ then I would look at what formulae used for the pooled standard errors and the degrees of freedom.

Let's say the true (in the population) covariance $covariance(x_1, x_2)$ of $x_1$ and $x_2$ equals $C$. It can then be proven that the covariance of the sample means $\bar{x}_1$ and $\bar{x}_2$ is equal to $\frac{C}{N}$ with $N$ being the sample size. In words: if the two variables themselves show covariance, then their sample means also show covariance (over repeatedly sampling from the population, that is). This means that the variance (over repeatedly sampling) of the difference $\bar{x_1} - \bar{x_2}$ is equal to:
$var(\bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_2) = var(\overline{x_1-x_2})=var(\bar{x}_1) + var(\bar{x}_2)
- 2*covariance(\bar{x}_1, \bar{x}_2)=$
$var(\bar{x}_1) + var(\bar{x}_2) - 2*\frac{C}{N}$
However, if the data for the two groups are independent, their sample means are also independent, meaning their covariance is zero, and then:
$var(\bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_2) = var(\bar{x}_1) + var(\bar{x}_2)$
The above shows that, if there exists a positive covariance in your two variables, then the variance of the difference of the sample means is $2*\frac{C}{N}$ smaller than in case the two groups would be considered as independent. The same holds for the square roots of these variances i.e. for the standard errors of the difference between the two sample means, used to calculated the t-values. As a result, a given difference between two sample means, can be insignificant when assuming independent samples, but significant when assuming dependent samples.
